# Can I use QApplication AND QCoreApplication?

Tags: qt, qapplication, qcoreapplication

I have a console application using QCoreApplication in Qt5. This application has different functions like "printABC" or "printSUV". The output will appear in the terminal. 
Now I want to make a Gui, where I can push the buttons "printABC" or "printSUV" and the output will appear in the terminal too, so that it is 'easier' to use the application. 
In Qt5, I can make a console application using QCoreApplication, which I have already done. 
So my question is how can I add a QApplication which runs along the way? 
In the docs, it is recommended to create a QApplication/QCoreApplication in the main function, so how can I create both?

Comment: QApplication inherits from QCoreApplication so you don't really need an instance of each.

Comment: I just left an answer... but to clarify, when you push one of these buttons in the GUI, do you actually want the output in the terminal from which the GUI was launched?  Or would you just show the data in the GUI itself (which is what I assumed in my answer).  

You can always print to `stdout` (or `cout` or `qInfo()`, etc). The only trick is if you are targeting Windows and you want the console to stay attached to the application after startup (to show any output), instead of returning to the command prompt like it would by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily have a single application which supports both command-line (terminal) mode and GUI mode.  <strike>Just use `QApplication` (or `QGuiApplication` for QML-only app).</strike>

*UPDATE* 1: The commenters are correct, it would be better to instantiate `QCoreApplication` or `Q[Gui]Application` depending on which is actually needed...

Then, for example, if a user passes CLI options, you just run the function(s) and send the result to `sdtout` (presumably like you're doing now). Otherwise show the GUI and use the same functions but to display the data some other way (in the UI).

*UPDATE* 2: ... So it would be better to parse the command line first and determine which Q*Application "flavor" should be used...

If you haven't yet, you can look into [QCommandLineParser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qcommandlineparser.html) to help handle the CLI options. Just keep in mind that it works exactly the same with a `Q[Gui]Application` as well.

*UPDATE* 3: ... In fact `QCommandLineParser` can be used before a `Q*Application` is created. One just needs to call `parse()` with a list of options from `argv`, instead of `process()` with the app instance. See code example below.

In `main()`, handle any CLI options first. Then to NOT launch the GUI you could simply `exit(0)` from `main()` before calling `app.exec()`.

A basic example:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication *app;

    QCommandLineParser clp;
    clp.setApplicationDescription("My app does great things.");
    clp.addOptions({{"cli", "Use CLI interface"}});

    QStringList opts;
    for (int i=0; i < argc; ++i)
        opts << QString(argv[i]);

    clp.parse(opts);
    if (clp.isSet("cli"))
        app = new QCoreApplication(argc, argv);
    else
        app = new QApplication(argc, argv);

    ...

    return app->exec();  // or maybe just 0, or app->exit(), if no event loop is needed.
}
```

If you want to show the output in the console from which the application was started, then you can still simply print to `stdout` (or whatever you're doing now). However if you want this to work on Windows, additional steps may be required... and there are a few things to consider. This would really be the topic of a different question, I think. IMHO mixing the two (GUI in one window and output in console) could be rather awkward, and showing output in GUI makes it all nicely self-contained.

Comment: Not really. A command-line variant should not even attempt to initialize gui resources, nor load gui-specific plugins. Thus, creating a `QApplication` when it's known that the startup is gui-less, is usually wrong. Typically the arguments are parsed, and then you decide whether to instantiate a `Q[Gui]Application` or `QCoreApplication`.

Comment: In fact, in Linux, a QApplication base app will crash if you try to run it in a terminal without a $DISPLAY environment variable.

Comment: @JoshuaClayton Thanks for reminding me about this. I've updated my answer to hopefully be more accurate.  And yes, w/out a `$DISPLAY` `Q[Gui]Application` cannot run (although I've only encountered that situation on remote sessions myself).